# Understanding Geo Permissions

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

From: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181108-International-SMS-Messaging-Geographic-Permissions-Geo-Permissions-and-How-They-Work

> Messaging Geographic Permissions generally work based on the country code of the destination phone number.

Assuming I have Canada and the USA enabled in my Geo Permissions, does the above mean—with the understanding that nothing is guaranteed here—I can send SMS to a Canadian mobile phone number anywhere in the world, or do I need to enable geo permissions for "Country X" for a Canadian mobile phone number to receive an SMS while that phone number is in Country X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the country code of the destination matters, not the country in which this number is connected to the network.